# Code for Redirection Not Working

Tags: phalcon

I am having some problems with redirection on Phalcon 0.8b.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {
    public function loginAction() {
        if($this->session->get('user')) {
            $this->response->redirect('users/view/');

            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the code checks if the user is logged in, and then redirects them. I am not getting a redirection to happen, however. It just white screens on me. Am I doing something wrong? The documentation hasn't been very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'exit' is avoiding that the response headers be sent to client, the following must work:

```
<?php

class UsersController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {

    public function loginAction() {
        if($this->session->get('user')) {
            return $this->response->redirect('users/view/');            
        }
    }
}
```